# Select only the text inside div of sibling with class name, having many families of same class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent, siblings

I wanted to copy the texts when the copy button is clicked. But, it copies the last(3rd) paragraph text when pressing any of the three buttons. It suppose to find previous sibling and copy that text when that particular button is clicked.

Here's my code. I think, I went wrong in the sibling thing. Let me know what I did wrong here:

```js
//finding text to copy
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.phc-hashtags-box-button', function () {
  $(this).closest('.phc-hashtags-box').find('.phc-hashtags-box-tags');
  copy = copy +$(this).text();
    });
});

function copyToClipboard(element) {
    var $temp = $('<input>');
    $('body').append($temp);
    $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    $temp.remove();
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>      
 </head>
 <body>            
  <div class="phc-home-hashtags">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="phc-hashtags-box">
     <h3 class="phc-hashtags-box-title">Dog1</h3>
     <p class="phc-hashtags-box-tags">#dog #dogstagram #instadog #dogsofinstagram #worldofdogs #dogslove #cutedog #doggy #igdogs #dogs #pet #dogoftheday #myfriend #doglover #ilovemydog #ilovedog #doglove #doglife #mydog #happydog #1st</p>
     <button onclick="copyToClipboard('.phc-hashtags-box-tags')" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
    </div>
    <div class="phc-hashtags-box">
     <h3 class="phc-hashtags-box-title">Dog2</h3>
     <p class="phc-hashtags-box-tags">#dog #dogstagram #instadog #dogsofinstagram #worldofdogs #dogslove #cutedog #doggy #igdogs #dogs #pet #dogoftheday #myfriend #doglover #ilovemydog #ilovedog #doglove #doglife #mydog #happydog #2nd</p>
     <button onclick="copyToClipboard('.phc-hashtags-box-tags')" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
    </div>
    <div class="phc-hashtags-box">
     <h3 class="phc-hashtags-box-title">Dog3</h3>
     <p class="phc-hashtags-box-tags">#dog #dogstagram #instadog #dogsofinstagram #worldofdogs #dogslove #cutedog #doggy #igdogs #dogs #pet #dogoftheday #myfriend #doglover #ilovemydog #ilovedog #doglove #doglife #mydog #happydog #3rd</p>
     <button onclick="copyToClipboard('.phc-hashtags-box-tags')" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To clarify my understanding of code:
1. you click a button.
2. An input element is appended to end of body element.
3. This input is populated with the text values of the clicked element.
4. You run execCommand to copy this content.
5. Remove the input element.
Is this accurate?

Comment: the input text has to be the texts above the respective button clicked. here, my code copies the last one for all 3 buttons.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Instead of picking by class which gets all of the element with that class, limit your find to the `parent()` div of the button and it will only get the relevant text:</strike>

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.phc-hashtags-box-button', function () {
        $(this).parent().find('.phc-hashtags-box-tags');  // notice the change on this line.
        copy = copy +$(this).text();
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

***Working solution:***

Now i noticed - you are not passing a single element to copyToClipboard.

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('.phc-hashtags-box-tags')" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
```

is sending the saving to copy the last element from 3 found with this. Try instead:

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard($(this).parent())" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>
```

Comment: I don't get it clearly. The change doesn't make any difference. Explain please

Comment: @SubashMatheswaran indeed you are right. The problem is in the `<button onclick="copyToClipboard('.phc-hashtags-box-tags')" class="phc-hashtags-box-button">Copy</button>` check my edit

Comment: I believe just changing it to "copyToClipboard($this)" would also work with his current code as is.

Comment: @CodeAt30, You are correct about my answer being wrong and I've updated it accordingly.

However, I think that your solution might have in issue in that the user is trying to only select the text of the paragraph element, not the parent .phc-hashtags-box container element.

Comment: instead of "copyToClipboard($(this).parent())" I tried "copyToClipboard($(this).prev())" it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you pass '.phc-hashtags-box-tags' to the onclick attr of the button elements, it is matching all of the elements with that class and returning the last match for the value of your function.

<s>Instead, try changing the button onclick handler to:</s>

<s>copyToClipboard($this)</s>

That said, the execCommand function is not working in the provided snippet so verifying is difficult.

Perhaps try passing IDs or try to architect a more elegant solution. So many relative jQuery selectors will inevitably cause bugs as complexity grows.